# Is there a way to list distinct field results from multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a few tables where I want to look at distinct values for a number of fields within them.

Eg.

```
ID | Category | sub_category | item
```

Is there a way where I can return a unique result set for each field?

Essentially I just want to see all distinct values for a different columns in a table within one result set.

I've tried joins but i need the results to be mutually exclusive of one another.

[image]

Each returned field won't necessarily have the same matching number of rows either.

Comment: SQL is about relations. If I understand correctly, you want to show unrelated data, however. One category, one subcategory, one subsubcategory in the first row. Next row shall show another category, another subcategory, another subsubcategory. No matter whether the category is somehow relateted to the subcategory and subsubcategory or not. Correct? Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Correct. Instead of running three different queries to get the results individually I just want to run one query to return an unrelated resultset.  Using MySQL.

Comment: Then I would go with Gordon's first approach. It doesn't give the DBMS too much work and you get all data in one go. However, I still wonder what this result may be good for. You are getting sub categories without any reference to their categories. It's like being told to read page 25, but you don't know which book. Or getting street names and you don't know which city a street resides in.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner this is a very unique use case. It is really more just about a list of items from the same table for specific fields. I understand this is not what relational database query languages are built for, but it helps me know what unique items exist.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use `union all`?

```
select distinct 'category', category
from t
union all
select distinct 'subcategory', subcategory
from t;
```

EDIT:

If you want the values in different columns:

```
select c.category, s.subcategory
from (select category, row_number() over (order by category) as seqnum
      from t
      group by category
     ) c full join
     (select subcategory, row_number() over (order by subcategory) as seqnum
      from t
      group by subcategory
     ) s
     on c.seqnum = s.seqnum;
```

You can extend this for additional columns by adding more subqueries and `full join`s.

EDIT II:

Older versions of MySQL support neither window functions nor `full join`.  You can do something similar, enumerating each value and then aggregating:

```
select max(category) as category,
       max(subcategory) as subcategory
from ((select (@rnc := @rnc + 1), category, null as subcategory
       from (select distinct category from t
            ) c cross join
            (select @rnc := 0) params
      ) union all
      (select (@rns := @rns + 1), null as category, subcategory
       from (select distinct subcategory from t
            ) s cross join
            (select @rns := 0) params
      )
     ) sc
group by rn;
```

Comment: Sorry I updated the example resultset to an image. Original post wasn't showing actual expected results, due to formatting. However would union just list unique values underneath each other in one column?. I don't think making the entire union query a subquery to another result would work either for what i'm after

Comment: @Cotcho_K . . . "I just want to see all distinct values for a different columns in a table within one resultset." This would appear to do what you want.

Comment: i don't think the version of MySQL I'm running supports the "over" statement as it's failing on the first part. I've tried to use over for a different solution but no go. Is there an alternative way of doing this? Or am I out-of-luck if i don't update MySQL?

Comment: @Cotcho_K . . . This is standard SQL.  If you are using a particular database, then the question should be appropriately tagged.

Comment: Apologies for that. I'm still grasping some of the nuances of various database implementations hence I wasn't wanting to tag something too specific and left it general. Totally understand my approach wasn't correct.

Comment: `select tmp.business_unit, tmp.level, tmp.classification
from 
((select business_unit, row_number() over (order by business_unit) as seqnum from retail_salaries_labour_act group by business_unit) b`.  Yields this output. 
 _SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by business_unit) as seqnum from retail_salaries_labour_act group by busi' at line 3_

Comment: I used your enumeration example and it worked fine, but i needed to alias the (@rnx := @rnx + 1) columns so the group by would work. Without out it the group by was failing. Not a problem but i like the solution. Just what i needed.